# Error:(1531, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'cropImageStyle'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

This is a section of values.xml

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault" ns2:ignore="NewApi">
<item name="cropImageStyle">@style/Widget.CropImageView</item>
</style>
```

Gradle

```
 compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.networkingapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 8
        versionName "2.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

I also have a red line error at this

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.+'
```

Comment: how do I fix this ?

Comment: There is no style attribute named `cropImageStyle` in `android:Theme.DeviceDefault`

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @tahsinRupam yes it is defined. I already checked that.

Comment: @halfer Okay but i am really in pinch now, and need this solved quickly.

Comment: You can always consider paid one-to-one support, such as AirPair or TopTal. You're sure to find urgent help there, since you'd be paying for the privilege.

Comment: @PrinceAli where is it defined ? Can you show it please ? I've searched in the source file themes_device_default.xml, couldn't find any.

Comment: @tahsinRupam in styles.xml                                                                     <style tools:ignore="NewApi" name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault">
        <item name="cropImageStyle">@style/Widget.CropImageView</item>
    </style>

Comment: @tahsinRupam I am also getting this in values.xml Resource Registered by thisuri i s not recognized xmlns:ns1="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.android.com/tools"